# Unity attach Object to other Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to attach an Projectile to the Player if he gets hit.

Im currently using this code:

`transform.SetParent(player.transform);`

But this doesn't work as expected.
It seems to follow only movement caused by the Player-Object and not its Rigidbody mean the Projectile will follow this:

`transform.position -= transform.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;`

But not this:

`rb.AddForce(transform.up * forceMult);` or Gravity

So I need a way to make the Projectile also follow the movement caused through the Rigidbody.

Anybody know a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to add the projectile to the player if he gets hit?

Comment: To make it visible that he gets hit. The Projectile is a Arrow. The Idea is inspired by Minecraft.

Comment: and do you do anything to the arrow after you've attached it to the player? Because if the player now moves the arrow should follow because it's parented.

Comment: destroy it after 5 Seconds using a IEnumerator.

Comment: and what exactly doesn't work? the shooting, how the arrow moves, how the arrow moves if the player got shot?

Comment: how the arrow moves if the player got shot. If the movement of the Player is caused from its Rigidbody as described above the Arrow dont moves. If using transform.position on Player the Arrow moves with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the arrow and the player via. RigidBody isn't possible from just parenting, because
regarding moving of objects parenting only helps with changing the transform of children if the transform of parent objects changed.

Therefore you should probably get the Arrow Rigidbody and move it via. `rb.AddForce()` as well.

**In public Variables of Player add:**

```
Rigidbody rbArrow;
```

**When you parented the arrow to the player call this function from the player:**

```
transform.SetParent(player.transform);
player.GetArrowRB();
```

**New Function in the Player:**

```
public static void GetArrowRB(){
    rbArrow = GetComponentInChildren<RigidBody>();
}
```

**Movement Code:**

```
// Move Player
rb.AddForce(transform.up * forceMult);

// Move Arrow
rbArrow.AddForce(transform.up * forceMult);
```